# JSDoc static function: specify return type based on static caller type

Tags: javascript, inheritance, jsdoc

Given the following, where a static function is defined once in the parent but usable by itself and all child types, is there a way to write some JSDoc to indicate that the return type = the caller type?

i.e. such that following the code below, intellisense would suggest `specificProperty` against `specificInstance.{...}`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    class Generic {

        static instances = [];

        static getInstance() {

            if( !this.hasOwnProperty('instances') ) this.instances = [];

            if( this.instances.length ) {

                return this.instances[this.instances.length - 1];

            } else {

                let instance = new this();
                this.instances.push( instance );

                return instance;

            }

        }

    }

    class Specific extends Generic {

        specificProperty;

    }

    let specificInstance = Specific.getInstance();

    console.log( specificInstance, Generic.instances, Specific.instances );

</script>
```